# add easing effect to jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

starting by this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('h1').hide();
        $('img').hide();
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });
 $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        $("h1").slideDown(3500);
        $('img').each(function(){$(this).show('blind',5000)


        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
    });

</script>
```

how can i add easing effect to the show function?

these are the cdn in my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is dangerously close to being down-voted - because it shows no research effort.  That is the most common reason for down votes.  Cool Avatar though.

Comment: ok, i read someting but i dont understand how implement easing functionality, i try for example: $(this).show('scale', {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeInBounce', 
}); but seems doesn't work

Comment: You can add what you did as an answer to your own question, and click the grey check mark.

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved, the previous code select only all images, now i wrapper all of them in divs box and select divs instead, the final effect results much better